# C printf/read Collission

Tags: c, parsing, io

I'm currently trying to get this piece of code working:

```
//TODO THIS IS NOT WORKING
printf("WARNING: THE USER INPUT WILL OVERWRITE THE FILE \"%s\". ARE YOU SURE? [Y/N] ", output_file_name);
int c;

while(read(0, &c, 1) == 1) {
    if (((unsigned char) c) == 'y')
        printf("YES");
}
```

**What I'm expecting the code to do:**
I was expecting to get the text

***WARNING: THE USER INPUT WILL OVERWRITE THE FILE "FILENAME". ARE YOU SURE? [Y/N]***

printed in the command line. And to be able to write something, after pressing *enter* I expect to see the text ***YES*** printed as many times as given 'y's in the previous input. Instead this is what I get:

```
./myprogram.o
I type things.
Including yyyy
ydkfasjf
yay
Now I'm tired and will press ctrl+d to write EOF to stdin...
WARNING: THE USER INPUT WILL OVERWRITE THE FILE "FILENAME". ARE YOU SURE? [Y/N]YESYESYESYESYESYESYESYES
Matthias@BASH ~/folder/
```

What is happening here? I think that somehow the printf and read functions collide... Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: `fflush(stdout);` after the first `printf()`?

Comment: `int c;` --> `char c`

Comment: `c` is an `int` which is probably 4 bytes, but you are reading only 1 byte. This leaves `c` consisting of 3 uninitialized bytes.  To fix this just make `c` be a `char` in the first place.

Comment: You *could* replace `(unsigned char)c` with `*(char *)&c` although that is silly compared to the more obvious solution of using a char in the first place

Comment: @M.M  Same idea about `char c` within < 1 second of each other!

Comment: @M.M: True, but most systems today are little-endian, so changing `int` to `char` wouldn't actually make a difference.

Comment: I think there are more embedded ARM devices (e.g. smartphones) around than there are x86-like PCs. In any case that's no justification for having broken code

Comment: re. `./myprogram.o`, typically the `.o` file extension would be used for object files, not executables

Comment: I counted as many YES as there are y in the input. Seems like it's doing what it should. Not sure what the code before this is but most of the input is ending up in the read command that will loop until it hits the EOF.

Comment: anyway - the call to `read` will read any bytes which have been input yet but not previously read. You described that this was your exact situation.  If you don't want this behaviour you will have to insert code that reads and discards any previously-entered characters, before entering this loop

Comment: @M.M: I'm with you, the code *should* be fixed. *But*! This question is about *specific* behavior of a *specific* program. The textual input suggests a keyboard as I/O, which makes x86 more likely than ARM. Also, `read()` takes a `void*`, so passing an `int*` is fine.

Comment: @FrankM Good eye.  8 `'y'` and 8 `"Yes"`.  does exactly as OP's code directs.

Comment: @EOF the call to `read` is correct , the problem is `(unsigned char)c` afterwards (which, as you point out, might appear to work correctly due to implementation details)

Comment: If you just want to consider first character you get you must not read in a loop.

Comment: Ok, I added a fflush(stdin) and changed the int to char, but it doesn't make a difference. I also isolated the code in its own program without any other code. Its freaking me out.

Comment: @Test, nobody suggested `fflush(stdin)`.  `fflush(stdout)` was suggested.  (Attention to detail)  See [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791865/c-printf-read-collission#comment55350883_33791865)

Comment: flush(stdin) does not have a well defined behaviour. flush(stdout) should make the printf be flushed to the screen. If this is all the code that is running that should make the printed text show up before you start typing

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry fflush(stdout) fixed the problem with the warning message not being printed before reading, but the "YES"s are still printed AFTER everything is read.

Comment: Update 2.0: If I change the 'printf("YES");' to 'return 0' (in main). Than the program returns after the first newline, not the first end-of-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdout` is often *line* buffered.  To force output to occur before the next line of code add `'\n'` to the output or use `fflush(stdout)`.

Also change `int c` to `char c` to properly read data into `c`.

```
printf("WARNING: THE USER INPUT WILL OVERWRITE THE FILE \"%s\". ARE YOU SURE? [Y/N] ", 
    output_file_name);
fflush(stdout); // *****
// int c;
char c;

while(read(0, &c, 1) == 1) {
    if (((unsigned char) c) == 'y') {
      printf("YES");
      fflush(stdout); // *****
    ]
}
```

Comment: That fixed the problem with the warning not being printed before reading, but "Yes" is still not printed after a 'y'+newline.

Comment: @Test, Did you add _both_ `fflush(stdout)`? (Attention to detail)

Comment: Now it works actually you didn't edited your answer yet, when I wrote the comment and tried it in the meantime. Thank you!

Comment: @Test The _initial_ edit said "To force output to occur before the next line of code add '\n' to the output or use fflush(stdout)."  That applied to `printf("WARNING: ....`, as you tried  and to `printf("YES");` which is the same problem just solved.  [patience grasshopper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGblsNXkJog)